# Connecting vb.net to foxpro when published

Tags: vb.net, database-connection, foxpro

I'm working on a vb.net web application which needs to connect to a foxpro database. I have used the following connection string:

```
<add name="FoxProConnection" connectionString="Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=Path\Database.DBC;Collating Sequence=machine;"
  providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
```

This is working fine when I run on my development machine.  However when I publish it to our web server the connection fails (although no error message is output to the screen). I have confirmed that the file is accessible from the server, it has permissions to be read by both the account I am logged into the system as and the account the application pool runs under and have also checked vfpoledb.dll is present and registered on the webserver.

The database is stored on a separate server and so has a full UNC path in the data source.

Any help would be appreciated as I've been banging my head against this for a while.

Comment: Does your server have the proper drivers installed ? I mean, it could be you can't user `VFPOLEDB` yet on this while you can on your machine because you installed foxpro on it. Sorry if that's a stupid question, but that's a classic : you install it, develop for some months then when you deploy you forgot you even installed it on your computer...

Comment: The drivers were installed by our network team during the last round of updates and I'm assured it was done.

Comment: Reinstall VFPOLEDB drive under your user and then try to use your app under the same user.